# Function() got multiple values for argument 'pk'

Tags: python, django, typeerror, django-urls

My program currently needs to print reports for each database entry in the settings model.

It reads the pk of the model and uses that to check the items of the settings entry.

However I get a `trialBalanceMonthly() got multiple values for argument 'TBMreports_pk'` error when I click on the button that is supposed to print the report.

Here is my code :

**reportsHome.html:**

```
{% for x in model %}
             <a href="#" class='list-group-item active'>{{ x.Complex }}  Reports</a>

        <div>
            <hr>
             <a href="{% url 'trialBalanceMonthly' TBMreports_pk=x.pk %}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" >{{ x.Complex }} Trial Balance Monthly</a>
             <a href="{% url 'trialBalanceYearly' TBYreports_pk=x.pk %}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" >{{ x.Complex }} Trial Balance YTD</a>
            <br>
             <a href="{% url 'incomeStatementMonthly' ISMreports_pk=x.pk %}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" >{{ x.Complex }} Income Statement Monthly</a>
             <a href="{% url 'incomeStatementYearly' ISYreports_pk=x.pk %}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" >{{ x.Complex }} Income Statement YTD</a>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <br>
{% endfor %}
```

**Views.py** *(I have removed some of the code that generates the variables to make this a more reproducible question)*

--*This is what each of the reports views functions look like*

```
def trialBalanceMonthly(TBMreports_pk):
    pkForm = get_object_or_404(SettingsClass, pk=TBMreports_pk)

    complexName = pkForm.Complex

        ### Printing Trial Balance PDF
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=TrialBalanceMonthly' + \
                                          str(datetime.now()) + '.pdf'
        response['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary'

        content = {'printDescM': printDescM, 'printAccM': printAccM, "xtrbMonth": xtrbMonth,
                   'xCreditTotalM': xCreditTotalM, 'xDebitTotalM': xDebitTotalM, 'complexName': complexName,
                   'printZeroM': printZeroM}
        html_string = render_to_string('main/reports/trialBalanceMonthly.html', content)
        html = HTML(string=html_string)

        result = html.write_pdf()

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as output:
            output.write(result)
            output.flush()

            output.seek(0)
            response.write(output.read())
    else:
        redirect('main/reportsHome')
```

**Urls.py:**

```
    #Print Each Report
    path('accConnect/trialBalanceMonthly/<int:TBMreports_pk>' , views.trialBalanceMonthly, name='trialBalanceMonthly'),
    path('accConnect/trialBalanceYearly/<int:TBYreports_pk>' , views.trialBalanceYearly, name='trialBalanceYearly'),
    path('accConnect/incomeStatementMonthly/<int:ISMreports_pk>', views.incomeStatementMonthly, name='incomeStatementMonthly'),
    path('accConnect/incomeStatementYearly/<int:ISYreports_pk>', views.incomeStatementYearly, name='incomeStatementYearly'),
]
```

The exact error message I get is below *(when I click on the Trial balance monthly button)*

```
TypeError at /accConnect/trialBalanceMonthly/2
trialBalanceMonthly() got multiple values for argument 'TBMreports_pk'
```

Comment: It should be ```def trialBalanceMonthly(self, request, TBMreports_pk):```

Comment: @SaadZimat , Thank you -- I have added just the "self" in my function definition and this has worked. The "request" will not poss through as the function is used to print a pdf file.